# How do I deploy my box.net application

Tags: box-api

I have create an box.net application according to the documentation. 
Now, I would like to share the application with my colleges. Does anyone knows, how I can make it? IMPORTANT, I dont want to deploy it in public.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your application a hosted application (i.e. it has its own website) or is it a file action?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of Application you've created.   There are fundamentally 2 types of apps in the Box "App Marketplace"

1) Apps that run on a server at a URL you own.  Box sends calls to you, either for file-actions (think right-click, open-with kinda stuff), or for webhooks.

2) Apps that are built for a specific device (like an iPhone or Android).  They show up in our marketplace, but the download links take users to the itunes or an android store to download the app.  These apps call into Box via APIs (see https://developers.box.com/docs)

If you've built a #1, then you need to figure out where you want to host the software you wrote.  Box makes it easy to host it on Heroku, or CloudFoundry, or Parse, so you can get going quickly, without having to provision your own hardware, etc.

So, it really depends on what kind of application you've built.